# How to properly mock properties that will be used in init block?

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, mockito, mockk

When we create a new `class A` in test it inits our values and in the `init` block that values are passed to the `class B`, only after that the values getters are mocked.

The main problem is that **I want to pass the mocked values to class B in init block**.

*Why do I need that?*

Assume that `class A` implements some Callback that is triggered by `class B` inner logic of which is using these Vals and we need to test the contract between these classes.

```
class A(
    private val b: B
) {

    val val1: SomeVal = SomeVal()
    val val2: SomeVal = SomeVal()

    init {
        b.setVals(val1, val2)
    }
    
    fun doSomeWork() {
        b.doAnotherWork()
    }
}

classB {

    private lateinit var val1: SomeVal
    private lateinit var val2: SomeVal

    fun setVals(a: SomeVal, b: SomeVal>) {
         val1 = a
         val2 = b
    }

    fun doAnotherWork(): Int {
         return val1.SomeInt + val2.SomeInt
    }
}

class ATest {
    
    private lateinit var a: A
    private lateinit var val1: SomeVal
    private lateinit var val2: SomeVal     

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        val b = mockk<B>()

        a = spyk(A(b))

        val1 = mockk(relaxed = true)
        val2 = mockk(relaxed = true)
    
        every { a.val1 } returns val1
        every { a.val2 } returns val2
    }

    @Test
    fun test() {
        every { val1.SomeInt } returns 4
        every { val2.SomeInt } returns 6

        *someAssertion*
    }
}
```

Comment: How about adding a change listener and change the value to the mocked value?

Comment: Don't know about that, it would be easier to add private constructor with these values. But I would like to know if mockK lib provides some tools to deal with such cases.

Comment: There is still no solution although there have been some Github issues concerning this topic: https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/261 https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/437